Trying to remember a children's book about a boy who was a potato peeler for the king, and later served him ice cream
I am trying to remember a book from my childhood; it was old, around 1960-70, and a thick collection book.
The a story was along the lines of "A boy worked in the King's large kitchen and used to peel potatoes. He wanted to cook but no one let him. One day the King got bored of eating same, and ordered his cooks to make something unique. They kept trying but the King wasn’t pleased.
Eventually the boy came up with cold ice cream and hot chocolate poured over it. And the King became very happy".

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please ask two separate questions, one for each book. To make these works easier to identify, please add the kind of information listed at the tag wiki for identification requests. This includes where and when you read it, what the publication date seemed to be, what the book looked like, etc. Please edit your question to add these details about the first book, don't provide them in the comments. Thanks!

Second book had description of "The other book was a collection of stories too. The title had a boy sitting with his dad in a red flying car and had several other stories." if the querent wants to write another question for it.

@aim: When you return, you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

The story about the kitchen worker is "Hot as Summer, Cold as Winter" by Bernice Goddard. It appeared in the 1942 story collection More Streets and Roads, published by the American schoolbook publisher, Scott Foresman.  I remember reading this story when I was in school, and remembered its approximate title.
